# How to get byteArray or base64 string from RenderTexture Cocos2d-JS

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I am making a game on cocos2d-JS for facebook in which there is a requirement of sharing a screenshot of the game.

I am able to take the screenshot but now I am unable to upload it in the Parse.com server because it requires base64 format or byte array. I am unable to find any solution of converting Sprite in to this format.. Here's my code so result when I do addchild its coming proper .. I have also added my commented code so that it will help to understand that I have tried lot of things but couldnt achieve the same.

```
shareToSocialNetworking: function () {

    cc.director.setNextDeltaTimeZero(true);

    var newsize = cc.director.getVisibleSize();

    var renderText = new cc.RenderTexture(newsize.width,newsize.height);

    renderText.begin();
    cc.director.getRunningScene().visit();
    renderText.end();
    var result = cc.Sprite.create(renderText.getSprite().getTexture());
    result.flippedY = true;
    this._mainViewNode.addChild(result,6000);

    //renderText.saveToFile("screenshot.jpg",cc.IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG);
    //var based = renderText.getSprite().getTexture().getStringForFormat().toString();
    //var data = based.getData();
    var file = new Parse.File("screen.jpg", { base64: this.getBase64(result) });
    //var file = new Parse.File("screen.jpg", data, "image/png");
    var self = this;

    file.save().then(function() {
        // The file has been saved to Parse.
        alert(file.url);
     this.onSharePictureInfoLink(file.url());

    }, function(error) {
        // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
    });


    //
    //var ccImage = renderText.newCCImage();
    //
    //var str = ccImage.getData();

},
```

is there any workaround that can be done

Comment: You can try this:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44520608/how-to-get-sprite-pixel-alpha-information-in-cocos2d-js-c/45030826#45030826

Comment: You can try this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44520608/how-to-get-sprite-pixel-alpha-information-in-cocos2d-js-c/45030826#45030826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a private variable called _cacheCanvas, which is the instance of the offscreen canvas

you can simply do `renderText._cacheCanvas.toDataURL()`

Comment: Interesting! Does this work cross platform? Or is there another way to capture a screenshot in a cocos2d-js app running on, say, Android?

Comment: That's too bad.. Do you know of anyway to take a screenshot with a native app made in -js?

Comment: Hao Wu this was an interesting answee I am using canvas.toDataUrl though which also worked and @SebastiánVansteenkiste: I would write an answer for u to take a screenshot with a native app made in js

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste I have added an answer so that if any one wants they can refer..

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can take the screnshot from cocos2d-JS

```
 screenshot: function (fileName) {
        var tex = new cc.RenderTexture(winSize.width, winSize.height, cc.Texture2D.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA8888);
        tex.setPosition(cc.p(winSize.width / 2, winSize.height / 2));
        tex.begin();
        cc.director.getRunningScene().visit();
        tex.end();

        var imgPath = jsb.fileUtils.getWritablePath();
        if (imgPath.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        var result = tex.saveToFile(fileName, cc.IMAGE_FORMAT_JPEG);
        if (result) {
            imgPath += fileName;
            cc.log("save image:" + imgPath);
            return imgPath;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

then make a Java call from Javascript

```
 public static void ScreenShot()
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Cocos2dxHelper.getCocos2dxWritablePath() + "/" + "screenshot.png");

        String fileHolder = "SampleFolder";
        File filepathData = new File("/sdcard/" + fileHolder);

        //~~~Create Dir
        try {
                if (!filepathData.exists()) 
                {
                    filepathData.mkdirs();
                    filepathData.createNewFile();

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filepathData + fileHolder);
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    String toSave = String.valueOf(0);
                    out.write(toSave);
                    out.close();
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e1) {

            }   

            //~~~Create Image
            File file = new File("/sdcard/" + "Your filename");

            try 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                imageBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {}

            Uri phototUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, phototUri);
            //~~~Add Code Below
    }
```

Do not forget to add permission for external storage